# How to derive mathematically that derivative of |Ax-y|^2 with respect to A is 2|Ax-y| x^T

Tags: backpropagation, matrix-calculus, tensor

How to get transpose part when derive mathematically $$ \frac {\partial|Ax-y|^2}{\partial A} = 2|Ax-y|x^T $$

Comment: For more about the theory, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257579.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249404/matrix-derivative is one of several other closely related threads.  Search [matrix derivative](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=derivative+matrix).

Comment: Thank you very much @whuber